# does wso2 carbon 4.1 support felix OSGi container?

Tags: wso2

This [link](https://stratoslive.wso2.com/carbon/docs/about.html) suggests version 4.0.1 supports felix, but I can't find any information for 4.1.

Does wso2 carbon 4.1 support felix as an OSGi container?

If so:

- which version of felix?
- how is felix configured instead of equinox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 Carbon 4.1.0 is tested and documented only against Eclipse Equinox and that is the recommended OSGi container. Felix has not been tested for Carbon since version 2.0. Though theoretically it should be possible  to use Felix instead of Equinox it is not documented and tested for Carbon so you want be able to find any documentation on how it can be configured in WSO2 Carbon docs. would recommend you to use Equinox if possible. hope this will help you.

Regards